# how to render multiple line charts - highcharts on same page using highcharts react wrapper - highcharts-react-offical

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to render multiple line charts - highcharts on same page using highcharts react wrapper - highcharts-react-offical.

But last chart is getting replicated to all chart containers

Comment: Hi @user2865480, Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-firefly-b0d2h

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek - added example - https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-ives-y9t3q  - thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have used the same reference for chart options. As a solution you can use spread operator to create new object:

```
const LineChart = props => {
  ...

  return (
    <Box my={2}>
      <HighchartsComponent options={{ ...ChartOptions }} id={id} />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-rgb-tkoo5

Comment: Ah, yes - you are right. I have missed the rest of the options. You need to create a deep copy. Please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-rgb-tkoo5?file=/src/LineChart.js